# Aggregating on max date in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following three rows of data in BQ:

```
date        instance_id   value
2020-01-01  2            'hello'
2020-01-04  2             NULL
2020-02-03  3            'new'
```

How would I group to get the 'newest' value by date? I tried doing a join on the following:

```
SELECT * from `historical_prices` m1 join `historical_prices` m2 
ON (m1.instance_id=m2.instance_id and m1.date=max(m2.date))
WHERE date > '2020-01-01'
```

But got the following error:

> Aggregate function MAX not allowed in JOIN ON clause at [7:100]

What would be the proper pattern to use to get the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.historical_prices` t
WHERE date > '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY instance_id
```

Comment: what does `[offset(0)]` do here?

Comment: `[offset(0)]` - takes the first element from array and then `AS VALUE` makes sure that resulted struct outputs properly. You can experiment by removing those parts and see what will happen w/o them - :o)